# Attribute constructor can't use console.writeline

Tags: c#, custom-attributes

So I was curious about what would happen if I applied the CallerMemberName attribute to an Attribute's constructor's parameter.  Here is my very simple code.

```
class MyAttribute : Attribute
{
    public MyAttribute(string message, [CallerMemberName] string name = "none specified")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\{message}: \{name}");
    }
}
[My("Program")]
class Program
{
    [My("Main")]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var MyAttribute = new MyAttribute("Inner");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I ran the code and nothing happened.  So I put a breakpoint in the constructor to see if it would get hit.  It did indeed.  However, even though the Writeline call seems to be executing, nothing is showing up.  Why not?

Also, the breakpoint did not get hit for the [My("Program")] attribute.  Why not?

**EDIT:** According to SLaks's answer, there is a race condition could be fatal to the program. 
I changed the inside of the constructor to:

```
new Thread(() =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("\{message}: \{name}");
}).Start();
```

The Main and Inner attributes do print this way, but the Program attribute does not.  Why is that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug in the CLR loader.

If you run with the VS hosting process enabled and call `Console.WriteLine()` in the constructor of an attribute applied to the `Main()` function, or (IIRC) the class containing it, you will trigger a reentrancy race condition in the `Console`, and the `Console` will be completely broken for the lifetime of that program.

Don't do that.

Comment: @phil: Attribute constructors don't run unless someone fetches the attribute.

Comment: Why would the attribute constructor body ever run just because `Main()` carries that attribute? I do not understand the situation you describe.

Comment: @SLaks why did the Main attribute run?  AFAIK I didn't fetch it.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Because the `vshost` loader fetches `Main()`'s attributes to check for `[STAThread]`.